# vbscript, check computers on a network for a specific application

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to check if iTunes has been installed on computers that are on my network.  I'm using vbscript to do this, but I am not getting any results.  I know that the script is scanning the PCs because it takes a couple of minutes for it terminate.  I also know that there are several PCs that have iTunes installed on them.  Here is what I've coded up.

```
Dim inputFile
Dim objFSO
Dim fil
Dim line
Dim logFile


Set shl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Set inputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("pcList.txt", ForReading)


WScript.Echo "Computers will be checked for iTunes.exe.  Check log file for resuluts."

' If log file exists, append to it and do not over write.
if(objFSO.FileExists("LogFiles\iTunesCheck.txt")) Then
    Const ForAppending = 8
    set logFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("LogFiles\iTunesCheck.txt", ForAppending)
Else
    ' If log file does not exist, create one.
    Const ForWriting = 8
    set logFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("LogFiles\iTunesCheck.txt", True)
End If

logFile.WriteLine "Scan date and time: " & Now
logFile.WriteLine "Scan has detected iTunes in the PCs listed below."

While Not inputFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inputFile.ReadLine
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" &  line & "\root\cimv2")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from  Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        If objFSO.FileExists(line & "\C$\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe") Then
            logFile.WriteLine line
        End If
    Next
Wend

logFile.WriteLine
logFile.WriteLine
logFile.Close
Wscript.Echo "All done."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for `C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe` is a bad idea:

- system drive can be other than `C:`,
- on 64-bit Windows versions, iTunes is probably installed to `Program Files (x86)` rather than `Program Files`,
- the script probably needs specific permissions to access the admin shares (`C$`),
- and so on,

Instead of this, run the `Select * From Win32_Product Where Name='iTunes'` query against each computer and see if the result set is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

@Helen 's objections notwithstanding (since you may have an all 32bit environment with only C drives and be a domain admin) ...

It looks from this line

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" &  line & "\root\cimv2")
```

that your text file contains just PC names, one per line. I see you're are adding the "\\" yourself.
In which case I would suggest that you should include "\\" in the UNC string as well, as demonstrated here:

```
If objFSO.FileExists("\\" & line & "\C$\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe") Then
```

I'm also not sure why you're enumerating network cards. Is this to gracefully run zero times if the target machine is off ?

Comment: It makes sense to add  the \\.  Thanks for that heads up.  And yes I'm using win_32 networkconfiguration so it will bypass PCs that are offline without stopping the script.